# Configuring time out in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I've got a site which has an export feature. This feature can export parts of the database up to a full database export. This has been optimized a lot but still requires some 90-180 seconds to finish. Debugging and time outs aren't an issue, but live I receive a 504 gateway time out error after about 90 secs. I am guessing that IIS gets tired of waiting for the backend to respond and returns a 504. Is there any way to specify a longer time out, e.g. 5 minutes?

I've got an old executionTimeout setting set to 3600 which doesn't seem to do much any more (I believe it's an IIS <7 setting).

I've also tried this suggestion form another Stackoverflow question:

```
<configuration>
  <system.applicationHost>
  <webLimits connectionTimeout="00:01:00"
     dynamicIdleThreshold="150"
     headerWaitTimeout="00:00:30"
     minBytesPerSecond="500"/>
   </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

The above doesn't work, the config file is broken. Is the above supposed to work?

**Main question:** how/can I increase waiting time in IIS to avoid 504s?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't an IIS issue. I believe the old way of providing a timeout worked. We've got a reverse proxy with a short timeout, this was changed to a longer timeout which effectively resolved the issue.